# How to call expressions and assign them values

Tags: python, expression, call

I have a dictionary of many expressions, for example

```
g={'asd':x+y,'sss':x-y}
```

I would like to define two functions aa and bb that return the evaluated value of these expressions.

```
g={'asd':x+y,'sss':x-y}
def aa(x,y):
    return g['asd']
def bb(x,y):
    return g['sss']
aa(2,3)
```

However, I cannot make it correct.

Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Moreover, in fact I have many variables rather only `x,y`, but variables like x1,x2,x3...x100.
I also have many functions.

If to do it this way:

```
g = { 'asd': lambda x, y: math.exp(x)**y, 'sss': lambda x, y: x - y }
def aa(x,y):
    return g['asd'](x,y)
def bb(x,y):
    return g['sss'](x,y)
bb(2,3)
```

I will have to copy x1,x2,x3...x100 for 100 times. This is too huge.

Comment: You need a dict of functions, not of expressions. E.g. `g = {'asd': (lambda x, y: x + y), 'sss': (lambda x, y: x - y)}`, then `def aa(x, y): return g['asd'](x, y)` and `def bb(x, y): return g['sss'](x, y)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval:

```
g={'asd':'x+y','sss':'x-y'}
def aa(x,y):
    return eval(g['asd'])
def bb(x,y):
    return g['sss']
aa(2,3)
```

Comment: the variables have different names when calling.

Comment: Just use the lambda approach and pass in an array where each element of the array would be a different variable

Comment: what if I have many variables and many functions like is being revised in the question?

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries store values, not expressions.

The closest thing you can do is to store functions:

```
g = { 'asd': lambda x, y: x + y, 'sss': lambda x, y: x - y }
```

Then you can call them later:

```
print(g['asd'](2, 3))  # 5
```

Comment: I have revised the problem a bit, would you please take a look at it.